# How to extract an image which was blended into another using opencv or PIL in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a [base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD3iT.png) image and a [result](http://www.190734.webhosting17.1blu.de/images/result.png) image.

The "result" image was created blending a "second" image into the "base" image.
I´m looking for a way to extract the "second" image out of the "result" image.

I tried this code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
from pathlib import Path

HOME = Path().cwd()

img1 = Image.open(HOME / 'base.png')
img2 = Image.open(HOME / 'result.png')

diff = ImageChops.difference(img2, img1)

diff.show()
diff.save(HOME / 'second.png')
```

and got this ["second"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnePb.png) image as the difference of the two.

Unfortunately, remnants of the blue horizontal lines and the red vertical line in the base image can still be seen in the difference.
[Here is an enlarged section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxCXu.png)

How do i get rid of these? Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: For the example you have shown, you could probably just convert all blue and red pixels to white/gray. Or more simply, just convert the image to grayscale.

Comment: Hi, thx for your thoughts but that is not what i´m looking for. In mathematical terms if my base image has value 1 and the result image value 3, the second image has the value 2, as 1+x=3 -> x = 3-1 but using the difference on RGBA is not correct as i suppose the result image was not created by using addition but "blending". So there have been some mathematical operations doing the blending and i´m looking for reversing these.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a binary mask on an image with staples.

```
import cv2 

img1 = cv2.imread('AD3iT.png')
img2=cv2.imread('result.png')
diff=cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
diff=cv2.cvtColor(diff,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask=cv2.threshold(diff, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )[1]
mask=cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
out=cv2.bitwise_and(img2, mask)
```

[image]

The threshold level, you may have to try different.